# How to Put Thread into Array

Tags: java

how do we does that because i failed to google it. my attempt to make below statement working also return error. Could someone show me the way.

```
Thread[] = {Thread(calculateFile)} //wrong


//thread class
class calculateFile implements Runnable {     

}
public void run() {
    //do some stuff
    System.out.println("do some stuff");
}
```

**additional**
actually i have a group of thread that run concurrently, i have to wait for all the thread to finish running and then run other program after that. i believe part of doing that i have to put all the thread into array first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot variable name and `new` keywords.

Try something like this:
`Thread[] myThreadArray = {new Thread(new CalculateFile())};`

Also your calculateFile class has incorrect brackets, try this:

```
//thread class
class CalculateFile implements Runnable {     

    public void run() {
        //do some stuff
        System.out.println("do some stuff");
    }
}
```

PS: good convention is to start class names with capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to wait for all threads to finish their work before proceeding further, you are not forced to put all threads in an array, nor doing so will halt your code until all threads are done. What you need to do is [join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) each thread on your main thread.